# Find Last In and Last Out from attendance table MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL table for attendance which have records as below:

```
   Id   DateTime             Door Employee_id
    1   2016-01-01 08:00:00  In   100
    2   2016-01-01 09:00:00  Out  100
    3   2016-01-01 09:15:00  In   100
    4   2016-01-01 09:30:00  In   100
    5   2016-01-01 10:00:00  Out  100
    6   2016-01-01 11:00:00  In   100
    7   2016-01-01 12:00:00  In   100
    8   2016-01-01 13:00:00  In   100
    9   2016-01-01 13:30:00  Out  100
   10   2016-01-01 14:00:00  Out  100
   11   2016-01-01 15:00:00  In   100
```

I want the output as Last Clock In and Last Clock Out as shown below. If there are no clock out after last clock in, just ignore the clock in.

```
   Id   Clock In             Clock Out             Employee Id
    1   2016-01-01 08:00:00  2016-01-01 09:00:00   100
    2   2016-01-01 09:30:00  2016-01-01 10:00:00   100
    3   2016-01-01 13:00:00  2016-01-01 14:00:00   100
```

I really have no idea how to perform this. I have asked my colleagues and goggled for answers but no luck. Could appreciate any help from you guys. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variation of the gaps problem.  Start by enumerating the `in`s and `out`s so the groups of consecutive values have the same value.  Then you can just use aggregation.

So:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id,
       max(case when door = 'in' then datetime end) as clockin,
       max(case when door = 'out' then datetime end) as clockout
from (select t.*,
             @grp := if(@d = door, @grp,
                        if(@d := door, @grp + 1, @grp + 1)
                       ) as grp
      from t cross join
           (select @d := '', @grp := 0) param
      order by id
     ) t cross join
     (select @rn := 0) param
group by floor((grp - 1) / 2)
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d8116/1) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: appreciate your answer! I will try your suggestion and will let you know if it works. :)

Comment: Hi Gordon, the query works but it still give all sets of clock ins and clock outs, not the pairs of last in and last out only which I want. But glad you have gave me some idea.

Comment: It works perfect in SQL Fiddle but not in my local mysql. I edit the query and put WHERE employee_id = :employee_id AND datetime <= :datetime AND datetime >= :datetime . It give me all sets with NULL value for one of  each pair.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask another question.  There is no `employee_id` in your question and this answer seems to correctly answer the question you did ask.

Comment: Yes. Your answer did answered my question. Only I didn't get it work here. I will try to find why and maybe need to improve the codes to get it work. Thanks so much for the answer! :)

Comment: Gordon, I get it works now! I actually put the 'WHERE' in wrong line. Now, it's works perfect! Thank you for saving my life! :)

Comment: Hi Gordon, this code may not work if there are records with the door name other than 'In' and 'Out'. I cannot figure how to fix it. Mind to help me?

Comment: @Eddy . . . Either you use a `where` in the subquery or you should ask another question.  Your question really doesn't suggest that the value is anything other than `in` and `out`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with a demo.

SQL:

```
-- data
create table attendance(Id int, DateTime datetime, Door char(20));
INSERT INTO attendance VALUES
(    1,   '2016-01-01 08:00:00',  'In'),
(    2,   '2016-01-01 09:00:00',  'Out'),
(    3,   '2016-01-01 09:15:00',  'In'),
(    4,   '2016-01-01 09:30:00',  'In'),
(    5,   '2016-01-01 10:00:00',  'Out'),
(    6,   '2016-01-01 11:00:00',  'In'),
(    7,   '2016-01-01 12:00:00',  'In'),
(    8,   '2016-01-01 13:00:00',  'In'),
(    9,   '2016-01-01 13:30:00',  'Out'),
(   10,   '2016-01-01 14:00:00',  'Out'),
(   11,   '2016-01-01 15:00:00',  'In');
SELECT * FROM attendance;

-- SQL needed:
SELECT 
    @id:=@id+1 Id,
    MAX(IF(Door = 'In', DateTime, NULL)) `Check In`,
    MAX(IF(Door = 'Out', DateTime, NULL)) `Check Out`
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *, 
        CASE 
            WHEN 
                (door = 'In' AND @last_door = '') OR
                (door = 'In' AND @last_door = 'In') OR
                (door = 'Out' AND @last_door = 'In') OR
                (door = 'Out' AND @last_door = 'Out')
            THEN @group_num
            WHEN
                (door = 'In' AND @last_door = 'Out')
            THEN @group_num:=@group_num+1
        ELSE 0
        END door_group,
        @last_door:=Door
    FROM attendance 
        JOIN (SELECT @group_num:=1) a
    ) t JOIN (SELECT @id:=0) b
GROUP BY t.door_group
HAVING SUM(Door = 'In') > 0 AND SUM(Door = 'Out') > 0;
```

Output:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM attendance;
+------+---------------------+------+
| Id   | DateTime            | Door |
+------+---------------------+------+
|    1 | 2016-01-01 08:00:00 | In   |
|    2 | 2016-01-01 09:00:00 | Out  |
|    3 | 2016-01-01 09:15:00 | In   |
|    4 | 2016-01-01 09:30:00 | In   |
|    5 | 2016-01-01 10:00:00 | Out  |
|    6 | 2016-01-01 11:00:00 | In   |
|    7 | 2016-01-01 12:00:00 | In   |
|    8 | 2016-01-01 13:00:00 | In   |
|    9 | 2016-01-01 13:30:00 | Out  |
|   10 | 2016-01-01 14:00:00 | Out  |
|   11 | 2016-01-01 15:00:00 | In   |
+------+---------------------+------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> -- SQL needed:
mysql> SELECT
    ->     @id:=@id+1 Id,
    ->     MAX(IF(Door = 'In', DateTime, NULL)) `Check In`,
    ->     MAX(IF(Door = 'Out', DateTime, NULL)) `Check Out`
    -> FROM
    ->     (SELECT
    ->         *,
    ->         CASE
    ->             WHEN
    ->                 (door = 'In' AND @last_door = '') OR
    ->                 (door = 'In' AND @last_door = 'In') OR
    ->                 (door = 'Out' AND @last_door = 'In') OR
    ->                 (door = 'Out' AND @last_door = 'Out')
    ->             THEN @group_num
    ->             WHEN
    ->                 (door = 'In' AND @last_door = 'Out')
    ->             THEN @group_num:=@group_num+1
    ->         ELSE 0
    ->         END door_group,
    ->         @last_door:=Door
    ->     FROM attendance
    ->         JOIN (SELECT @group_num:=1) a
    ->     ) t JOIN (SELECT @id:=0) b
    -> GROUP BY t.door_group
    -> HAVING SUM(Door = 'In') > 0 AND SUM(Door = 'Out') > 0;
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Id   | Check In            | Check Out           |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
|    1 | 2016-01-01 08:00:00 | 2016-01-01 09:00:00 |
|    2 | 2016-01-01 09:30:00 | 2016-01-01 10:00:00 |
|    3 | 2016-01-01 13:00:00 | 2016-01-01 14:00:00 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This answer works perfect! Thank you so much! You save my life!