# Combine Time in and Time out in one row mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently, I have this table: `date_time_records` where all of the time in and out of employees are being saved.

[image]

As you can see all of the data of time in and out are being stored for each row.

and these data can be identified if it is time in or out using `state` field

Time in = `C/In`

Time Out = `C/Out`

**Expected Output**

Now I'm trying to do a query something like this

[image]

Where you can see the same employee record but different day

and you can notice that the time in and out is being arranged.

Here's my code

```
 SELECT
      a.id,
      a.ACNo,
      a.name,
      a.email,
       (SELECT MAX(datetime) FROM date_time_records WHERE id = a.id AND state = "C/In") as time_in,
       (SELECT MIN(datetime) FROM date_time_records WHERE id = a.id AND state = "C/Out") as time_out,
  FROM `date_time_records` as a GROUP BY datetime ORDER BY `created_at`  ASC
```

Please disregard the created_at

I'm using `datetime` since the system is capable to do a bulk upload of time in and out. of past data.

Comment: employee will only ever have one on and one out per day? There will always be matching pairs of in and outs? Nobody has an in before midnight and an out after midnight?

Comment: Sample data as text (which we can use) is more useful than images which we cannot use.

Comment: employees have multiple C/In and C/Out for the same day.. I just want to get the first in and last out of the employee. Since employee have multiple time in and time out for the same day you just need to get the first in and last out for that day only.

Comment: 'employees have multiple C/In and C/Out for the same day' - there is no 'same day' in your sample data but there is a created_at in your query? Whats the significance of created_at?

Comment: I updated the question please disregard the created_at. Assuming I have multiple same day in my data. You can consider it

Comment: Please read my updated question salmon

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find Last In and Last Out from attendance table MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931382/find-last-in-and-last-out-from-attendance-table-mysql)

Comment: will try to check on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT ACNo, Name,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN state='C/In' THEN DATETIME END ORDER BY DATETIME ASC),',',1) AS time_in,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN state='C/Out' THEN DATETIME END ORDER BY DATETIME ASC),',',-1) AS time_out,
       DATE(DATETIME) AS recDate
FROM   date_time_records
GROUP BY ACNo, Name,recDate
ORDER BY ACNo;
```

Using `GROUP_CONCAT` then `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to get the first & last value.

Fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bfkoKK13kcE8NYVzo71Zi3/3

Comment: @RaeIan . . . This is definitely not the best way to solve this problem.  First, `GROUP_CONCAT()` has built-in limits that might cause intermediate values to overflow.  More importantly, converting date/time value to strings is unwarranted.  Third, the conversion to strings and the use of `GROUP_CONCAT()` is more expensive than necessary.  You can see my answer for a more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT dtr.id, dtr.ACNo, dtr.name, dtr.email,
       MAX(CASE WHEN dtr.stat = 'C/IN' THEN dtr.datetime END) as time_in,
       MIN(CASE WHEN dtr.stat = 'C/OUT' THEN dtr.datetime END) as time_out
FROM date_time_records dtr
GROUP BY dtr.id, dtr.ACNo, dtr.name, dtr.email
ORDER BY MIN(created_at) ASC
```

Comment: this query missing `END` in the `CASE` expression and if you look at this fiddle : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bfkoKK13kcE8NYVzo71Zi3/5 , the grouping by `dtr.id` will show all rows. However, if grouping by `dtr.id` is removed the result in `time_in` and `time_out` doesn't return the correct time for `Employee3`. I agree that this is much efficient compared to my answer but so far it hasn't fulfill the OP's requirement. Looking forward for a fix :)

Answer (score -1):

Could you just log a user's time in/time out separately from the date? That'd make the min/max query for time in/time out on a daily basis a lot simpler.